# Prevents the deletion of contracts that are in active status

Tags: custom-object, validation-rule, standard-objects

I want to give a validation on contract that when contract status is on active nobody can't delete the contract. But I can't do this. If anyone have solution give me the solution it helps me a lot.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you facing issue when you say "I can't do it"?

Comment: The validation rule does not run during deletion. You should create a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules cannot do it, you need a (before delete) trigger to prevent the deletion of a record and you must call [`addError()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError).

If the only check is against Status field, the trigger is quite straightforward:

```java
trigger ContactTrigger on Contract (before delete) {
    // Better move this logic into an handler class
    for (Contract record : Trigger.old) {
        if (record.Status == 'Active') {
            record.addError('You cannot delete an active Contract');
            // or
            // record.addError(System.Label.Active_Contract_Deletion_Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the trigger shouldn't hold the logic, it should be moved into an handler, and instead of hardcoding and error message you could define a [Custom Label](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_about.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: @MdMamunurRashid You're welcome. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.